# How to inject viewcontrollers in viewcontrollers in swift ? To have a fixed top menu

Tags: ios, swift

Here is a draft of what I would like to do : 
[image]

I would like to have a main container, which will be used to trigger Menu from everywhere.

I try to do this thanks to `view.addSubview` and `addChildViewController`.
But the second view disables the first one. It simply goes over.

How could I do to keep both functionalities ?

**UPDATE:**

I found a way that works, but it seems dirty :
I just move down the secondView frame according to the menu height, here is the code :

```
var test = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestViewController") as TestViewController
var test2 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Test2ViewController") as Test2ViewController
//proposeOrChooseViewController.delegate = self

view.addSubview(test.view)
addChildViewController(test)
test2.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, test2.view.frame.size.width, test2.view.frame.size.height)
view.addSubview(test2.view)
addChildViewController(test2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the frame of second view controller's view set correctly? Visually you can test it by setting a background color of view.

Also you might want to explore the Container View in storyboard. Container View lets you add a View Controller as child of another view controller.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer :) Yes I tested with a different background color and its frame is correctly set ! Thanks for the tip about container view, I am going to dive in ! Sounds interesting!